# automl vision create model gives error - 'request contain 'invalid argument'

Tags: google-cloud-automl

We are on paid billing subscription for GCP compute engine.

We are trying to evaluate **`'automl'`** - create model gives error
**`-request contain 'invalid argument'`**

(1)
**data folder structure:**

```
\severity_train\test\class1\2 images  
\severity_train\test\class2\2 images  
\severity_train\train\class1\2 images  
\severity_train\train\class2\2 images  
\severity_train\validation\class1\2 images  
\severity_train\validation\class2\2 images
```

(2)
**Loading images:**

```
gsutil -m cp -R e:\software\iam\severity_train\ gs://deeplproj-vcm/img/
```

**Loading csv file:**

```
gsutil cp e:\software\iam\damage_vehicle_2.csv gs://deeplproj-vcm/csv/
```

(3)
**Import data set:**

```
python automl_vision_dataset.py import_data ICN6998417958897537479 gs://deeplproj-vcm/csv/damage_vehicle_2.csv
```

(4)
**Model creation:**

```
python automl_vision_model.py create_model ICN6998417958897537479 vehicle_model 1
```

gives error

**`- request contain 'invalid argument.'`**

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 10 examples per class. See more here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare